Slow read performance when reading volume
I am trying to read an windows volume but for some reason the performance does not match if compared to reading an file located at same volume. In both cases buffering is disabled (enabling it does not have any difference).
The volume is opened with DOS Device path
string volumePath = @"\\?\c:";
File.OpenHandle(volumePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.RandomAccess | FileOptions.WriteThrough | (FileOptions)0x20000000);

Then read with RandomAccess
await RandomAccess.ReadAsync(handle, buffer, offset, default).ConfigureAwait(false);

When reading file from the volume the speeds reach up to 5Gb/sec
When reading volume speeds hardly hit 200Mb/sec
Perhaps I have missed something ? Is OS treats volume handles differently?
Hope someone could shed some light on this.
Thanks!

Why await ReadAsync() and not just Read()?  And how large are your buffers? And are they as large as when reading from a file?

Did you use the same code to read? How did you measure the speed?

@MikeNakis Its async because it is by nature of the code use, its Async IO we talking about, tried with different buffers raging from kb to mb, bigger buffers give better performance but nowhere near what expected.
The speeds themselves don't matter, just by running same code its clear that in volume case the speed are 10,20 slower.

It looks like the problem did not have anything to do with the file handle being a volume, the performance difference seem to be related to a mix of how tests where conducted and how SSD drive works.
After conducting read tests on free surface of the drive/volume the speed was reaching expected levels, all the software that where used to conduct benchmarks would create the test files on that free surface and were able to produce the high read speeds.
